# Workflow engine supporting CMIS

Tags: workflow, cmis

I am looking for a workflow engine that supports the CMIS protocol.

Requirements:

- CMIS ChangeLog events can be used to trigger transitions/events.
- Workflow actions can act on CMIS content (should be easy with the REST API)
- Admin web interface to see current workflows, upload new workflow definitions
- Graphical workflow designer
- Free, ideally open source